# I need to change my url when i click on some block on my page

Tags: javascript

I need to change my url when i click on some block  on my page.  For example: my url now is https://localhost:44311/faq. On this page i click on block(it is href) with information.(All information is hidden).After click all information is visible.and my url should be changed like this(https://localhost:44311/faq/#NameOfBlock)

[href doesn't work. I use jquery to find this href:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcIYF.png)

I use Jquery to find this href but how to change url i don't know

```
$(".is-accordion-submenu-parent").on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).children("a").attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: While I can't help you with that question, a few tips: Please post code in code boxes and not as normal text. Secondly, please show in more detail what you have tried so far, what the expected result was and where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then you should use this for URL redirection:

If you want to simulate a click on a link, use the location.href

`window.location.href = "https://localhost:44311/faq/#NameOfBlock"`

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, then use location.replace

`window.location.replace("https://localhost:44311/faq/#NameOfBlock");`

UPDATE: But if you want to change the URL without reloading the page, you can use this:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```